# Jmeter CSV data set config run script correct even after providing incorrect username and password

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to run performance testing using 100 users by using JMeter CSV data set config, I have added 100 different users in CSV file which are incorrect.
when i run the script in run properly, i was expecting it should show me the error than username and password is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter automatically treads [HTTP Status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below `400` as successful, it doesn't do any extra checks.

So if your application responds with HTTP Status Code below 400 JMeter won't fail the sampler. If you need to test whether is user logged in or not add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it to test whether response contains something which indicates logged in user, i.e. `Welcome` text or something like that or vice versa, that it doesn't contain elements of login page.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more about conditionally failing JMeter samplers using [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions).

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri, It helps me a lot, now i am trying this in my project, if i stuck please help me.

Comment: I tried applying the same but in Response Assertion , not getting what to add for verification purpose